# Spark 2 application on the same time

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using spark streaming and saving the processed output in a data.csv file

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, new Duration(1000))
JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = jssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999);
```

At the same time i would like to read output of NetworkWordCount data.csv along with another newfile and process it again simultaneously

My Question here is

Is it possible to run two spark applications at the same time?
Is it possible to submit a spark application through the code itself

I am using mac, Now i am submitting spark application from the spark folder with the following command

```
bin/spark-submit --class "com.abc.test.SparkStreamingTest" --master spark://xyz:7077 --executor-memory 20G --total-executor-cores 100 ../workspace/Test/target/Test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 1000
```

or just without spark:ip:port and executor memory, total executor core

```
bin/spark-submit --class "com.abc.test.SparkStreamingTest" --master local[4] ../workspace/Test/target/Test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

and the other application which read the textfile for batch processing like follows

```
bin/spark-submit --class "com.abc.test.BatchTest" --master local[4] ../workspace/Batch/target/BatchTesting-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

when i run the both the applictions SparkStreamingTest and BatchTest separately both works fine , but when i tried to run both simultaneously, i get the following error

Currently i am using spark stand alone mode

```
WARN AbstractLifeCycle: FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:4040: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
```

Any help is much appriciated.. i am totally out of my mind

Comment: Is there a reason to first write the output of the network capture and read it again to process it? (i.e. Do you require the raw capture data?) There're few options, but first let me know about that requirement.

Comment: what spark version are you using?

Comment: Spark Version 1.0.2, i am trying to cache the data while streaming
streaming durations is 1s i process the data received in one second and save the result in cache and for the next streaming session i tried to fetch the cached result but its empty so i am trying to save the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/monitoring.html

> If multiple SparkContexts are running on the same host, they will bind to successive ports beginning with 4040 (4041, 4042, etc).

Your apps should be able to run. It's just a warning to tell you about port conflicts. It's because you run the two Spark apps in the same time. But don't worry about it. Spark will try 4041, 4042 until it finds an available port. So in your case, you will find two Web UIs: ip:4040, ip:4041 for these two apps.

Comment: what do you mean by multiple SparkContext? How can I achieve it on single host? the statement inside document is also open ended.

Comment: More precisely, I mean starting multiple Spark applications.

Comment: ah. okay Its clear now. Also I executed with the same approach for testing and got the context :). thnx